# Table() oracle function in Mysql

Tags: mysql, arrays, list

I am looking to compare an array of ids with my table id collumn

For example my array will be like :

```
(1,2,3)
```

and the db table will be  something like:

```
id      
---
1
3
5
```

the result that i am looking for is :

```
2
```

It is possible to convert array into a Table and do the join on Mysql?

Comment: can't you just use the `IN` operator?

Comment: it is not the case, i am looking to the the reverse here

Comment: So you want items in the array but not in the table?

Answer (score 3):

You would do this with a left outer join:

```
select list.n
from (select 1 as n union all
      select 2 union all
      select 3
     ) list left outer join
     dbtable t
     on t.n = list.n
where t.n is null;
```

So, you can "convert" the array to a table by creating the appropriate code as above.

Comment: its seems logical your solution, but i have a long list, so i need to write a script to make a list with Select x union